# Definition of $\mathscr{U}$-small set

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a Grothendieck Universe. Then Kashiwara defines a set $X$ to be $\mathscr{U}$-small if it is **isomorphic** to a set belonging to $\mathscr{U}$. What does he mean by isomorphism here? He doesn't define it anywhere before. Is it just a bijection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it’s just a bijection.${}{}$